# NDSolve cannot solve an ODE system with functions given as integrals-

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

The problem is that my Mathematica programme cannot solve the differential algebraic equations system. To simplify the problem as much as possible I will consider only the differential equation (which cannot be solved by it either)

$f(x,y(x),z(y(x)),y'(x))=0,$

where $z(\eta_e(x))$ is given by integrals

$z(\eta_e(x))=\int_0^{\infty}g(\eta_e(x),p)\mathrm{d}p.$

The (simplified) version of my code

```
z[x_] := Integrate[(p^2*
    Sqrt[1 + p^2])/(E^((0.6*Sqrt[1 + p^2])/0.18) - ηe[
      x])^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]*D[ηe[x],x];

f[x_] := (5/x)*z[x] - 2.8*^15*x^8*(- (3*x^2)/2 + x^4/2)*(2*x^4)^3

xi = 1.01; 
xf = Sqrt[2000];  
ηi = 0.5;

sol = NDSolve[{f[x] == 0, ηe[xf] == ηi}, ηe, {x, xi, xf}, 
MaxStepFraction -> 0.001,Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
```

As you see the programme just cannot finish the computation...

Comment: Few readers are likely to sort through all your code.  So, I recommend that you simplify your sample problem still further - one integral and one differential equation.  Also, use the same symbols in your code as you do in your LaTeX expressions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey! I simplified the code.

Comment: By `Derivative[1] ηe[x]` do you mean `D[ηe[x], x]`?  Also, `E3[x]` is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I improved it now, thanx. By the way, how do you copy the code from Mathematica Notebooks: I always have this `Derivative[1] ηe[x]` instead of `D[ηe[x], x]`...

Comment: Copy the code (highlight, right click, choose "Copy") from your notebook and past it into the question.  The Greek characters will not look right, but it still will work.  You can edit the Greek characters after the pasting, if you like.  Better options are described [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second term in `f` is very large, preventing `DSolve` from working even after I had fixed other issues.  So, I replaced it with a constant and also reduced `xf`.  I suggest that you verify the accuracy of `2.8*^15*x^8*(- (3*x^2)/2 + x^4/2)*(2*x^4)^3`.  Here is what I used.

```
z[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(p^2*Sqrt[1 + p^2])/(E^((0.6*Sqrt[1 + p^2])/0.18) - y)^2, 
    {p, 0, Infinity}]
eq = (5/x) z[ηe[x]] ηe'[x] - 10^-3 == 0;
xi = 1.01; xf = 12;  ηi = 0.5;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq , ηe[xf] == ηi}, ηe, {x, xi, xf}]
Plot[sol[x], {x, xi, xf}]
```

[image]

Reasons for other changes to the code are as follows.

- `z` cannot evaluate the integral unless `ηe[x]` is passed to it.  Even then, `Integrate` cannot evaluate the integral, but `NIntegrate` can.  Finally, `NDSolve` must be able to solve symbolically for `ηe'[x]` before beginning, but cannot when it is inside a function.  Designating the argument of `z` as numerical simply is good practice.
- Defining `f` as a function does not work well for similar reasons.  Just write the equation out and pass it to `NDSolve`.
- The options provided to `NDSolve` seemed to add no benefit and, in one instance, caused problems.

After the code is running properly with the correct expressions for the multiple functions and equations, it may prove to be quite slow.  If so, try evaluating the integrals for reasonable ranges of the `ηe` and create `InterpolationFunction`s from the resulting tables.  Then use them instead of the `z` in `NDSolve`.

Comment: @PaulJef  Certainly, you are welcome.  What did you determine about the term `2.8*^15*x^8*(- (3*x^2)/2 + x^4/2)*(2*x^4)^3`?  Also, if the answer meets your needs, please accept it by clicking the grey check mark to the left of the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, it came from my ad hoc simplification of the system, so it is probably not so relevant. Now I'll try to implement your suggestions to my actual system. I don't know if I can make use of the integral interpolation, since my actual integrals depend on two parameters. Also there's a question of error estimation in this case.